# Azure DevOps Pipelines: File not found: 'C:\agent\externals\tf\tf.exe'

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps Pipelines.  I've set up a simple Pipeline to copy a text file from one location to another location.

When I run the Pipeline, I get this error:

> File not found: 'C:\agent\externals\tf\tf.exe'

I'm not sure if I have to set up an environment or not.  It let me specify the source and destination locations in the file copy task.

1. Which computer C:Drive is DevOps looking at for this, the C:Drive where TFS is, or when source or destination servers? 'C:\agent\externals\tf\tf.exe'
2. Can I change where DevOps looks for the tf.exe file, if so where are those settings located? I didn't see them in where I checked.

For this discussion, the environment is on-prem Windows, Azure DevOps Server.